# How to solve such expression containing probability and random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to solve the following expression containing probability and random variables but not getting it correctly.

$I = \text{Pr}(X>\frac{\phi}{P_s},AY<\gamma_{th})$ -----(1)

where, $\text{Pr}$ indicates probability , $X$ and $Y$ are exponential random variables, $\phi,P_s,A$ and $\gamma_{th}$ are constants.

I know that I will have to do the integration. However I am not getting it properly.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply...Yes the random variables are independent ...But how do you derived this answer...

Comment: If the r.v.'s are independent then the probability is $$\large{\left(1-e^{-\lambda \cdot \frac{\gamma_{th}}{A}}\right) \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot \frac{\phi}{P_s}}}$$

Comment: $P(X<t)=1-e^{\lambda \cdot  t}$, where $X\sim \textrm{exp} (\lambda)$

Comment: Yes....I know the derivation in case of $\text{Pr}(AY<\gamma_{th})$.....But how to deal with $\text{Pr}(X>\frac{\phi}{P_s})$

Comment: Yes sir........the one with greater than sign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $P(X>t)+P(X<t)=1 \Rightarrow P(X>t)=1-P(X<t)$

Another approach is to deal with integration:

$$P(X>t)=\int_t^{\infty} \lambda\cdot e^{-\lambda x} \ dx=\left[-e^{-\lambda x}\right]_t^{\infty}=0-(-e^{^{-\lambda t}})=e^{^{-\lambda t}}$$

Comment: Ok... Thank you sir...Got the first approach clearly...in second approach you are actually integrating the PDF... Is my understanding correct...?

Comment: @Saru Yes, I´ve integtated the pdf in the limits ($t,\infty$), since it is are greater than $t$ releation. You´re welcome.